# Django: ValueError: Unable to configure handler - [Errno 2]

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am very new to Python and Django and is currently busy learning myself through tutorials on www.djangoproject.com. I am using PyCharm and working on OS X El Capitan. I have imported a project from GitHub and created a virtual environment for the project interpreter based on Python 3.5.1. In the vm I installed django.

I then activated the vm.

Now.. I started by trying to execute simple commands in the terminal like `python manage.py startapp deonapp` and `python manage.py runserver` but each time I get an error which I pasted below.. What did I miss? I cannot seem to find the /log/ directory?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 558, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 731, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1008, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/deon/Documents/PyCharmProjects/Developments/deonproject/log/debug.log'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/deon/Documents/PyCharmProjects/Developments/deonproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/deon/Documents/PyCharmProjects/Developments/deonproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/deon/Documents/PyCharmProjects/Developments/deonproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/deon/Documents/PyCharmProjects/Developments/deonproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 566, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/deon/Documents/PyCharmProjects/Developments/deonproject/log/debug.log'
```

Comment: You should give a link to the project. Looks like that project is expecting to log to somewhere that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I managed to fix it. The log directory was not created because it was excluded in the .gitignore file. I completely forgot to look what was excluded :). I created the directory manually and now it passed the error.

Comment: I faced a similar issue. All my log directories were cleaned up by some "cleaning" application I used earlier to free up some space.
I ended up recreating those folders and touching log files inside them.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix it. The log directory was not created because it was excluded in the .gitignore file. I completely forgot to look what was excluded :). I created the directory manually and now it passed the error.
Deon

Answer (score 1):

you can add this in setting.py

```
LOG_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'log')
```

or

```
if not os.path.join(LOG_PATH):
    os.mkdir(LOG_PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers can be true in most of cases, But In my case log directory was created, **But** log dir had permission issue to my user. simply using `chown` to my user (my case `www-data`) solved the problem.

(In my case):

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/log/django/
```

use your `username:user-group` instead of `www-data:www-data` and your log dir instead of `/var/log/django/`.

Answer (score 0):

Traceback says, that it's no "log" directory.

1. Create directory with name `log` in path `/Users/deon/Documents/PyCharmProjects/Developments/deonproject/`
2. Create empty file `.gitkeep`
3. After creating .gitkeep file, push it to GitHub