# Django ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'

Tags: django, environment-variables

I have a hard time because I'm a django beginner.
Please share your wisdom in solving this problem.

```sh
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Problems arise when a project is executed.
I don't know the cause of the problem

settings.py

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

...

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG=os.getenv('DEBUG')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_ENGINE'), 
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
...
```

and then I met this error message.

```sh
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 562, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 735, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 148, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 55, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1087, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1116, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/logs/logfile'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 799, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 570, in configure
    '%r' % name) from e
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'
```

Is there something I'm missing?
What more information will be needed to solve this problem?

I'm sorry to send you a question with a little information.

thank you for watching
I'm waiting for answer

Comment: Do these following links answer your problem? Looks like django is trying to open a file that does not exists. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718630/django-logging-log-file-from-handler-not-found), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101488/valueerror-unable-to-configure-handler-file-errno-2-no-such-file-or-direct) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101715/django-valueerror-unable-to-configure-handler-errno-2)

Comment: Seem error is logging config. Please check the log directory. If not , please make dir before run project.

Comment: I really want to thank you for your help